# JComboBox.setSelectedItem behaves differently with nulls

Tags: java, swing, null, jcombobox

Running the program as is with these 2 lines commented out

```
//      comboBox.setSelectedItem(selected1);
//      comboBox.setSelectedItem(new Item(null,null));
```

It will generate a ComboBox with 3 items with the 1st item showing by default.

Remove the comment from the following line.

```
comboBox.setSelectedItem(selected1);
```

It will generate a ComboBox with 3 items BUT the 1st item showing is blank. Essentially no default item since it is searching for a null and doesn't find one.

Add the comment back to the following line :

```
//      comboBox.setSelectedItem(selected1);
```

And remove the commends from this next line.

```
comboBox.setSelectedItem(new Item(null,null));
```

It will generate a ComboBox with 3 items with the 1st item showing by default.

Both setSelectedItem() calls search for an item that doesn't exist but the end result is different. In one scenario, the default selected item is blank and in the other scenario the default selected item is the first.

What is the cause for the different behavior?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class JComboBoxDefaultSelection 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Object selected1 = null;
        Item selected2 = null;
        JComboBox<Item> comboBox = new JComboBox<Item>(new Item[] {
            new Item("Major", "red"), new Item("Critical", "dark"),
            new Item("Minor", "green") });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(comboBox);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
//      comboBox.setSelectedItem(selected1);
//      comboBox.setSelectedItem(new Item(null,null));
    }

}

class Item {

      private String name;
      private String color;

      public Item(String name, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      public String getColor() {
        return color;
      }

      public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return name;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Cause: specification - the documentation of [setSelectedItem](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object))  states that: "If anObject is not in the list and the combo box is uneditable, it will **not** change the current selection. . . . 
Parameters:
    anObject - the list object to select; **use null to clear the selection**"

Comment: Neither object is in the list so shouldn't they behave the same? Or is the issue that only the first object is null and that clears the selection. Although the second object is not in the list it is NOT a null object. I assume this means the default is to have the first item in the list selected???

Comment: haven't you read it **ALL**????? I've actually marked it in bold: "**use `null`to CLEAR the selection**" and since `Object selected1 = null;` you are using `null` when calling `comboBox.setSelectedItem(selected1)`, so the selection is cleared (or "blank" as you wrote)!

Comment: and, btw, `new Item(null, null)` **is not** `null`, despite full of it (its field being `null`) - it is being searched and not found in the list of items, so the selection is not changed (stays at the first item, the default after creation)

Comment: Just wanted to confirm my understanding. Thanks for for the replies.